# Defold, scale making sprites dissapear

Tags: sprite, scaling, defold

I'm trying to scale my sprite, but it keeps dissapearing. I used go.set_scale(4) which makes it dissapear. There doesn't seem to be anything on the defold page and I have even tried using manuel scaling with the properties options. Why can't I scale the sprite?

Do I need to make them tiles? Those scale fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that the game object/sprite isn't positioned at z-value 0 and when scaled 4 times it probably ends up outside the default -1 to 1 range that is visible in the render script: https://defold.com/manuals/components/#component-z-value